# basic Socket programming in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am attempting to create a very simple `Socket`/`ServerSocket` program in Java.  My two classes are listed below, both of which run on the same machine.  The problem is, the connection seems to be established just fine, but when I attempt to write over the socket from the client to the server, nothing seems to happen.  The server never returns from `in.readLine()`, and the program comes to a halt.  I cannot figure out why this is happening.

Here are my classes:

TheServer.java:

```
public class TheServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
        ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(2255);
        Socket sock = serv.accept();
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Connection established by Server");

    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != "Bye") {
            System.out.println(line + "Received");
            out.println(line.toUpperCase());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

TheClient.java:

```
public class theClient {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 2255);
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Connection established by Client");

    try {
        while (true) {
            BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            String line = read.readLine();
            out.println(line.trim());
            System.out.println(in.readLine().trim());

            if (line == "Bye")
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Are  you passing an end of line (\n) in the data?  I think I ran into this in the past too.  Since you are reading lines on each side, you need to send the EOL.

Comment: `println()` appends an EOL to every line it sends

Comment: I ran the fix and it looks like it works.  It looks like the termination case doesn't though.  != "Bye" may need to be  --> while (!(line = in.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("Bye")) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for PrintWriter object, after each write try,

```
    obj.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not flushing the outputstream, do `printwriter_obj.flush();`

You have to do this after sending each and every message.
I would suggest to add auto flush parameter to the Printwriter,like this:

```
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(OutputStream:socket.getOutputStream(),AutoFlush:true);
```